# Check if int_long variable first character is equal to a certain number in c

Tags: c, if-statement, indexing, cs50

I'm currently doing the cs50 computer science Harvard online course and my current challenge is to check if the first character inside a variable is equal to a number here is my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long card;
    char n = card[0];
    do {
    card = get_long("Enter Credit Card Number: ");
    } while (card < 15);

    if (n == 3) {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }



    /*
    AMEX\n 34 or 37;
    MASTERCARD\n 51, 52, 53, 54, or 55
    VISA\n  4
    INVALID\n
    */
}
```

the pseudo-code would go as follow

```
    if (input first number is equal to 3) {
        print "AMEX" //new line
    } else if (input first number is equal to 5) {
        print "MASTERCARD"8 //new line
    }
```

Here is the [Challenge link](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/1/credit/#luhns-algorithm)

I tried to do

```
if (card[0] == 3) {
    printf("AMEX\n");
}
```

But since it's not an array it didn't work.

i also try to search online for answers but since I'm not familiar with c at all (I learn HTML, css, javascript and react) i don't really understand the layout of c

Sorry if my post is kinda hard to read I'm new to this whole StackOverflow thing if you need anything else just ask please

Comment: `card` should be a string, not a number.

Comment: Anyway `long` won't have enough capacity if 32 bits.

Comment: Also, since n is a `char`, it'll be `n == '3'`, not `n == 3`.

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try that

Comment: Note that it will require at least a 64-bit integer to accommodate a 16-digit credit card number. And to extract the most-significant digit from said 16-digit number requires a mathematical operation: `n / 1000000000000000LL` will truncate the lowest 15 digits and leave you with the 16th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this (assuming `get_long` returns a 64-bit integer):

```
int main(void) {
    int64_t card;
    int n;

    do {
        card = get_long("Enter Credit Card Number: ");
    } while (card < 10000000000000LL);
    n = card / 100000000000000LL;
    if (n == 3) puts("AmEx");
    else if (n == 4) puts("Visa");
    else if (n == 5) puts("Mastercard");
    else if (n == 6) puts("Discover");
    else puts("Invalid!");
}
```

(Note that Discover Card #'s start with a 6)

Comment: Note the `'LL'` in `100000000000000LL` is OK, but unnecessary.

Comment: From the linked problem set: *"American Express uses 15-digit numbers, MasterCard uses 16-digit numbers, and Visa uses 13- and 16-digit numbers."* A rigid approach is probably not ideal here, and treating a CC number as an integer is not a great plan in general, since they hold no intrinsic mathematical value as a whole, even if the digits do on their own. This is a case of a flaw in the problem set by suggesting the use of `get_long` instead of working on string data.

Comment: That work I'll read the code you provided and learn from it thank you very much!

Comment: @chux -- that's only true on a 64-bit system

Comment: @SGeorgiades, True on all systems. The `LL` is not needed here.